# What is "Carry the bat" in Cricket?

Tags: cricket, terminology

I have heard the terminology "Carry the bat" in Cricket. What does it mean? When it is used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Carry the bat" is used when an opener (a batsman who play at number 1 or 2)  remains *not out* after the team is *all out*.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_the_bat):

> In cricket, the term carry the bat (or carry one's bat) refers to an opening batsman who is not dismissed ("not out") when the team innings is closed.

Here the term is used when the innings is closed due to all players are out or retired out or unable to bat.

The term is not used when the innings is except above reasons. E.g. declaring the innings, win the match etc.

The term is used like this:

> Rahul Dravid *carries the bat* for 146.

See the list of carrying the bat in:

- [Test](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/283149.html)
- [ODI](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/283150.html)

Answer (score 4):

It basically means that the batsman was at bat for the entire inning and, since he never got out, he "carried the bat" the entire time (as opposed to handing it over to another batsman once he was out).