# Why is Sachin Tendulkar's 200* not considered as carrying the bat?

Tags: cricket, terminology, trivia, records

I would like to know why Sachin's 200 not out in ODI against South Africa is not mentioned in carrying the bat record list of ODIs.

I found [a question regarding carrying the bat](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3182/what-is-carry-the-bat-in-cricket) in sports beta and in one of the answer there was a link of Cricinfo of carrying bat record list of both ODI's in tests and when I looked into ODI's list I just remembered Sachin's 200 not out against SA is not there in the list though he came opening and was there till the end of 50 overs. And in ODI record list, they have mentioned saying to carry bat the through, team isn't necessary to get all out but should have played complete 50 overs by opening might be in 1st or 2nd innings.

Can anybody answer me for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/3183/540) you have posted a question link:

> Here the term is used when the innings is closed due to **all players are out or retired out or unable to bat**.
>
> The term is not used when the innings is except above reasons. E.g. declaring the innings, win the match etc.

Also, from the [Cricinfo list](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/283150.html):

> Carrying the bat is defined as an opener batting through the innings to remain as the not out batsman with the team all out. **It does not apply to a team in ODIs batting the complete 50 overs with wickets still standing**.

Here [the team is not all out](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/441828.html). Just 50 overs are completed. So he is not carrying the bat.